# Specific text IF Statement in Excel

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I created a fairly simple If statement in Excel to keep track and classify some cost categories.

One of them is a set of number '8405-xxx'. 
I created an If(LEFT(A2950;4)="8405";"8405".

But then someone in the company decided to create 'GE8405-xxx'.  Which is the same as 8405.

I did look for a while but was not able to find a formula that could return '8405'.

Thank you.

Comment: take note that if GE8405-xxx was created and beleive they might get creative and create a lot more combinations.

Comment: when they add will it always be letters, can we just remove everything before the first number and after the dash?

Comment: @ScottCraner look below, works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to here it though that formula will only work for this one case, I was thinking more along the lines of what if they start modifying other cost categories.  I was trying to set some rules to give you a more robust formula that would work in any instance.

Comment: You can always come with a solution and I will try to implement it and give you feedback :) @ScottCraner.

I doubt it will be more then xx8405-xxx. The xx before 8405 can only be letters and the -xxx can only be numbers.

Comment: if the numbers are always 8405 then stick with the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(RIGHT(LEFT(A2950;6);4)="8405";"8405")
```

How it works:

- First you get the 6 chars on the left => GE8405
- Then you want to get rid of "GE", so use the right function => 8405

Comment: I read the comment you posted after the question, of course this will work only if they get creative but always keeping a two letters prefix

Comment: It works usually this way '8405-xxx' and in this case 'GE8405-xxx' ( xxx being a series of numbers that varies). It would return the last 4 characters being '-xxx', no?

Comment: Try it :) the LEFT function is executed first. So, if the beginning string is "GE8405-xxx", you will have "GE8405" as a temporary result. Then, with the RIGHT function, you take the 4 chars on the right getting the desidered 8405